# Where to get a Native Clock application for Galaxy Y?

Tags: clock

I have deleted the Native Clock application on my rooted Galaxy Y. Now I can't set alarms and such. Anyway to undo this or at least anywhere I can get the native clock app on android?

I tried searching at Google but nothing relevant came up.

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't want to use 3rd-party alarm clocks? There are free ones.

Comment: And didn't you do a proper backup before fiddling with the system? You could use that to restore then.